# read a websites html code, then select an element and then make an action on that element

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to know how Read a websites html code. Then i want to take a **specific** Element from the html code and make a request to make an action to the Element(e.g. Button,Textfield)

For example i take a websites URL, read the html code,take the element a button and then press the button from my Flutter App.

Answer (score 1):

Web Crawlers/**Scrapers** only works on mobile clients (or website with **CORS** enable).

You need to add the following libraries **http** and **html** inside your **`pubspec.yaml`**:

```
html: ^0.14.0+3
http: ^0.12.0+4 

// latest versions by Feb 18th 2020
```

to use it, create an **async** method to fetch the **URL** you want to "read":

```
Future<Response> _initiate(String url) async {
    Response response = await get(url);
    return response;
}
```

and then, use it this way, reading the specific **div, a, img**, etc you need:

```
_initiate(url).then((response) {
      var document = parse(response.body);
      var items = document.querySelector('div.groupHomeHeader-banner');
      var split = items.attributes.values.toList()[1].split('(')[1];
      var image = split.substring(0, split.indexOf(')'));
      var name = document.querySelector('a.groupHomeHeader-groupNameLink');
});
```

Every **Element** has different attributes. For example, an **InputElement** has the attribute **`'click()'`** and creates the desire effect.

Example of this will be:

```
var openDoc = document.querySelector('div.pdfInput') as InputElement;
openDoc.click();
```

Comment: even on ``` 'package:html/dom.dart'```